# How to Parse the Message received from GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting notifications from server but i am unable to parse the data properly.

this is what is get from extras.toString();

Bundle[{messageType=1, contentText=content body, from=23105361257, contentTitle=content title, **message=test message**, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, tickerText=ticker text message}]

i want to print only message value from the bundle in the notification.
and also if i get another notification.. i want to display it below in the same notification,in Bigview style. How can that be possible???

eg.

test message

another test message

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                sendNotification(extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("message", msg);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("New Notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher_icons)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(msg));

        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(msg);
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `extras.getString("message","not set!")` ?

Comment: What you getting in Intent if `HomeActivity.class`

Comment: @PratikButani-AndroidButs: Can you help me with the second part of it please? how to show the messages in big view. eg. whatsapp. if i get msgs from same user multiple times it shows  them in notification.. how to do that? at present.. notification gets replaced by new one.

Comment: May you have to Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`

Comment: nopes it didnt workout. i guess therez some problem with my code regarding bigview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send like:

`sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));`

instead

`sendNotification(extras.toString());`

So you will get **test message** in argument of `sendNotification()` and then you can pass it in `Intent`

Hope you will get it. Thanks.